# Calculator with equations?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, software-rec, equations, calculator

I'm running Windows XP SP3. I'd like an alternative to Windows' calculator with support for equations, so I don't have to fire OpenOffice just to compute simple equations.

Does someone know of a light desktop applications for Windows that offers a bit more than Calculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [Redcrab](http://www.redchillicrab.com/en/redcrab/index.html) it supports equations

Answer (score 1):

[SpeedCrunch](http://www.speedcrunch.org/) seems to fit your requirements. There's even a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/speedcrunch_portable) to run from USB.

Comment: Thanks guys. Both applications foot the bill, but SU doesn't seem to vote for more than one answer :-/